# Send Meteor Template to client on condition

Tags: meteor, reactjs, template-engine, meteor-blaze

I've been playing with Meteor recently, and one thing I can't wrap my head around is how to publish templates based on a certain condition, before they are sent to the client-side. Example:

```
<head>
    <title>Some partially authenticating app</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{> unauthorisedContent}}
    {{> authorisedContent}}
</body>
```

What I want to do is send the `{{> authorisedContent}}` template if and only if the client is logged in, and **not** send it then conditionally and then exclude it based on `if (!!Meteor.user())` on the client side. How can this be achieved? Is this also possible using React JS for Meteor instead of Blaze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible within the same Meteor application. Your two options for addressing this are:

1. Have a separate application for authorized content versus unauthorized content.
2. Ensure that you're not publishing data to unauthorized users who happen to figure out how to get the authorized content template to show up.

Most people go with option #2.

Comment: Perfect answer - if you happen to know, could you elaborate on if it's possible to pass Templates using DDP as a protocol communicating between microservices? Idea being I "cascade" the templates from the least to most authenticated. I'm not sure if this is a good idea because of latency between each connection (unless they run in parallel) - suggest resources if I'm asking the obvious about DDP conns (noob alert!)